# Haskell first steps compile error

Tags: macos, haskell, functional-programming

I've just installed Haskell platform full with the installer from here https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html

Now, as the noob I am,  i created a very simple program, just to see if it works:

```
f :: Int -> Int
f x = x + 2
```

but when i execute

```
runhaskell test.hs
```

it returns

> test.hs:0:53: error:
>
> • Variable not in scope: main :: IO a0
>
> • Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)

if i run

```
ghc test.hs
```

it returns

> The IO action ‘main’ is not defined in module ‘Main’

indicating just the first char of the first line "f"

Comment: Haskell expects an entry point to your program, in the form of a `main` function. If you want to load an interactive REPL, try `ghci test.hs` instead.

Comment: thank you very much, that is what i was looking for.

Comment: Since installing Haskell succeeded, the recommended next step would be to learn some Haskell. A good tutorial is available [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With your program you **have not instructed Haskell what the program should do**. You only have **defined a function**. That does not mean that Haskell will automagically call that function.

You need to define a function with a special name `main` (`ghc` has an option to specify another name, but let us ignore this for now). `main` is a function of the type `IO a`. It is a function that describes an action (`IO`) that is called when you execute the program.

Since you only defined a single function `f`, you probably want to test `f`.

So we can write a `main`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print (f 2)
```

Now if add this to the program. The compiler will generate an executable that will execute `main`. Here `main` is quite simple: we instruct it to `print` the result of `f 2`. So it will print `4`. We call `main` the *entry point* of the program.

You can also decide to run an *interactive* session instead. In that case you do not need an *entry point*, since you can decide in the interactive session what functions you will call.

You can for instance use `ghci file.hs` to start an interactive sesion, and run:

```
$ ghci testprogram.hs 
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( testprogram.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> f 2
4
```

So now we have called `f 2`, and the interactive session automatically prints the result `4`.

Comment: Oh yes very nice! That is what I was looking for, because at the University I used to write a simple function in a .hs file, than after clicking it an interactive shell was opened (we use Windows machines). So that was what I was looking for, the command ghci. Thank you very much!

Comment: I prefer `print (f 2)` since it avoids raising the question of what the `$` sigil means. Also I don't think there's much use in saying that `main` is a monadic function: "monadic" is confusing to a beginner, and "function" stands out as incorrect to an expert. I'd rather just say that "`main` is the IO action that is performed...", or even simpler than that "`main` is the entry point to the rest of your program."