# What are the differences between runghc and ghc?

Tags: ghc

What are the differences between **runghc** and **ghc**?

I ran a short program that seemed to compile fine with both, except that I got the following with **runghc**, but not plain **ghc**:

> error:
>
> - Variable not in scope: main :: IO a0
> - Perhaps you meant `min' (imported from Prelude)

[It seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46796275/4592583) that compiling things in **runghc**, those things need Main function, while plain **ghc**, doesn't?

Is that all?

Comment: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runghc.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`runghc` is used to *run* programs directly, not compiling them. A file without a `main` IO action can't be *run* as, by definition, there is nothing to run.

What `ghc` does with a file not containing a `main` is compile it as a *module*, to be imported by other haskell programs/modules - these are, of course, not runnable.