# How to call a function inside the code to return the degree of a polynomial?

Tags: haskell, math, functional-programming, polynomials, algebra

In haskell's Poly package polynomials like x**2 + -1 are represented by [ -1, 0, 2] so for calculate the degree of a polynomial, I need to calculate the length of the polynomial list - 1.

This is what I have done:

```
polyDegree :: (Num a, Eq a) => Poly a -> Int
polyDegree p = rawPolyDegree (trim (0==) p)

rawPolyDegree :: Poly a -> Int
rawPolyDegree p = rawPolyLength p - 1

rawPolyLength :: Poly a -> Int
rawPolyLength (ListPoly    _ _ cs) =    length cs
rawPolyLength (VectorPoly  _ _ cs) =  V.length cs
rawPolyLength (UVectorPoly _ _ cs) = UV.length cs
```

I tried to compile this code. but doesn't work this code output this error

```
 ghc -o main main.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )

main.hs:1:32: error: Not in scope: type constructor or class `Poly'
  |
1 | polyDegree :: (Num a, Eq a) => Poly a -> Int
  |                                ^^^^

main.hs:4:18: error: Not in scope: type constructor or class `Poly'
  |
4 | rawPolyDegree :: Poly a -> Int
  |                  ^^^^

main.hs:7:18: error: Not in scope: type constructor or class `Poly'
  |
7 | rawPolyLength :: Poly a -> Int
  |                  ^^^^

main.hs:8:16: error: Not in scope: data constructor `ListPoly'
  |
8 | rawPolyLength (ListPoly    _ _ cs) =    length cs
  |                ^^^^^^^^

main.hs:9:16: error: Not in scope: data constructor `VectorPoly'
  |
9 | rawPolyLength (VectorPoly  _ _ cs) =  V.length cs
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^

main.hs:9:39: error:
    Not in scope: `V.length'
    No module named `V' is imported.
  |
9 | rawPolyLength (VectorPoly  _ _ cs) =  V.length cs
  |                                       ^^^^^^^^

main.hs:10:16: error: Not in scope: data constructor `UVectorPoly'
   |
10 | rawPolyLength (UVectorPoly _ _ cs) = UV.length cs
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^

main.hs:10:38: error:
    Not in scope: `UV.length'
    No module named `UV' is imported.
   |
10 | rawPolyLength (UVectorPoly _ _ cs) = UV.length cs
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^
exit status 1
```

I researched here in stack overflow about problems compiling haskell function and I found a question about a simple algebra functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796205/haskell-first-steps-compile-error)
I understand that my problem is *that I have not instructed Haskell what the program should do* the answer of this question is this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print (f 2)
```

So accordingly to the question need to put this somewhere in my code but I don't know how where I have to put the values for this function?

I am studying with Programming in Haskell 2016 Graham Hutton 2nd Edition the book said is not important learn how to compile the snippets but I want to compile this snippets for check if my code is running. I am new in haskell, I am learning and interested in functional paradigm. I am using GHCi, version 8.6.5 Online Compiler for this.

Comment: You are referring to `Poly` in your code but ghc doesn't know about it. I guess you mean to work with the `poly` package. Do you have the package? Have you imported the module?

Comment: as @user1984 already statet its probably a problem of your imports... -> with importing Data.Poly I could solve  problem "Not in scope: type constructor or class `Poly'" - regarding the rest... are you sure about your data constructors? With a quick hoogle search I couldn't find them...

Comment: In addition when you call UV.length and V.length I assume you have some "qualified imports" - could you expand your code sniped with those?

Comment: I found that snippet [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/polynomial-0.7.3/docs/Math-Polynomial.html) press the #source option. is named -- |Get the degree of a a 'Poly' (the highest exponent with nonzero coefficient).

Comment: “In haskell polynomials like x**2 + -1 are represented by [ -1, 0, 2]” – no they aren't. Haskell itself knows nothing about polynomials. Of course, you can choose to represent them by lists or some vector or a custom data type or a ready implementation from a library, but then you need to have that either in your own code or import it.

Comment: You will need to understand basic error messages like `Not in scope`; as a beginner you'll make lots of errors (as an expert I make lots of errors!), and the compiler often gives you the information to very quickly resolve them, or at least know where to look. Searching for very generic terms like "problems defining Haskell functions" in response to any error message from the compiler won't get you very far very fast. If you don't understand the terms used in the first sentence of an error message (no shame in that!), it might be worth asking here for an explanation of the error message!

Comment: to check whether your code is running just load it into the interpreter, GHCi. no need to compile, for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven’t read this book, but I get the impression that it doesn’t intend for you to use a third-party package here.

Instead, *directly use a list*. A list of type `[k]` and length *n* can represent a polynomial with *n* coefficients of type `k`, in order from least significant (*x*<sup>0</sup>) to most significant (*x*<sup>(*n* − 1)</sup>). Then one way of calculating the degree is like you said, simply the length of such a list less one:

```
degree :: [a] -> Int
degree p = length p - 1
```

And you can rephrase this by introducing your own type synonym:

```
type Poly a = [a]

degree :: Poly a -> Int
degree p = length p - 1
```

This solution has some bugs, for example:

- What should happen if `degree` is given an empty list `[]` of coefficients? What happens instead?
- What should `degree [1, 0, 0]` evaluate to? What happens instead? (This is why the code you copied also requires `(Num a, Eq a)`.)

In the code you copied from the `poly` package, functions like `rawPolyLength` are operating on the library’s data representation, also named `Poly`. It has a few different constructors for different representations (lists, boxed vectors, and unboxed vectors). You haven’t defined anything like that in your code. If you want to practice *defining* functions operating on lists, just use `[a]`, or add `type Poly a = [a]` and use your own `Poly a`. You can use the functions of `ListPoly` as a *reference* for how to define these same operations on plain lists, the code just won’t be identical.

As in other languages, you would use an external package like `poly` if you wanted to use their implementation of polynomials *without* having to define them yourself. For learning Haskell, it’s advisable initially to stick to the `base` package (`Prelude`, `Data.List`, &c.) to get comfortable with the core vocabulary of the language.